# Is there any way to create multiple router-outlet with multiple outlet option OR without outlet in component url

Tags: angular, routes, router-outlet

I want to achieve a fully dynamic routing and component view. For that, I need to open multiple route in UI.

`{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'opt1,opt2' }, { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, outlet: 'opt1,opt2' },`

OR

Without outlet configuration, 
`{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },`

Is any of above configuration possible? For both above configuration, I am ready to manage which outlet option is available so will open my router/component inside available `router-outlet`

Have also added below in initial app.component.html
`<router-outlet name="opt1"></router-outlet> <router-outlet name="opt2"></router-outlet>`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
I have update the stackblitz to work with router.

---

You can't achieve that with multiple router outlets but you can try dynamic component rendering.The downside is that you will have to manage your URL if you want to enable navigation by URL. I've created a stackblitz with a simple demo.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o1lhnx

Comment: Good option... Thank you!!! I will try to implement using this approach.

Comment: Is there any way to get component from URL?